# Sonata admin dashborad block that could list details

Tags: symfony4, sonata-admin

I have tried to integrate blocks which is displayed properly but i want to list the recent updates done on each block in my dashboard it self

Comment: This is off-topic as per SO terms. Please refer [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it 
I had to create a BlockService for it and appropriate twig had to be written
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html